# Google Maps basic setup in Rails Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm having a beginner's hard time getting Google Maps to show in a Bootstrap modal in Rails.

Application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFm7OzAKuPbEa48b_aZ4S6JqMGVUCwwFs&callback=initMap", async: true, defer: true %>
```

And in the modal partial:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
```

The error in console at page load is:

```
"initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"
```

Which I have to assume is do to the fact that initMap is hidden in an unopened Modal on load.   Any hints as to a solution would be appreciated, I've been researching it for a couple of hours.

EDIT:    ... just as a side comment, and I know this is another question, but I previously had the Google places autocomplete installed and working, which I took out to get Google Map working, because it gave an error (have 2 google apis loading).     The previous application.html.erb for google places was

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFm7OzAKuPbEa48b_aZ4S6JqMGVUCwwFs&libraries=places", async: true, defer: true %>
```

.. how do i mix the two google api script tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try without using callback initMap in the UrL ..........

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFm7OzAKuPbEa48b_aZ4S6JqMGVUCwwFs", async: true, defer: true %>
```

Hope this will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Got it!   Thanks man.     Please see my EDIT for a related separate question, if you have another quick sec..